# Create a dynamic JSON with a plsql procedure for a tree diagram

Tags: json, d3.js, plsql

I want to create JSON code in the following structure:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
        }
      ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Of course my JSON would be much bigger. The data is stored in a table with one column with the ID and another column with the ID of the "parent-node". Now I want to create the JSON through an PLSQL procedure. Can anyone help me to get an idea how I can start? At this point I am looking for a base to solve this problem. Trees are making me mad everytime...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. with a loop and htp.p I create the JSON and read it with apex.server.process(...).
Very simple.

Comment: Hi Steve,could you please post sample query which constructs on this tree format.i have similar requirement .